# Test with Capybara cannot find a checkbox created using Simple Form association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capybara, simple-form

I have a form created using Simple Form, as such

```
<%= simple_form_for @organisation do |f| %>
  <div class="form-inputs">
    <%= f.association :causes, as: :check_boxes %>
  <div class="form-actions">
    <%= f.button :submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

The page works fine when I use a browser, but when I try to check this with Capybara, such as:

```
check('organisation_cause_ids_1')
```

And have tried many variations of this e.g.

```
find(:xpath , '//*[@id="organisation_cause_ids_1"]').set(true)
find("organisation_cause_ids_1").check
```

These always give an error:

```
 Failure/Error: check('organisation_cause_ids_1')
 Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   Unable to find checkbox "organisation_cause_ids_1"
```

The HTML generated by Simple Form is:

```
 <div class="input check_boxes optional organisation_causes">
   <label class="check_boxes optional">Causes</label>
   <span class="checkbox">
     <label for="organisation_cause_ids_1" name="organisation[cause_ids]">
     <input class="check_boxes optional" id="organisation_cause_ids_1" name="organisation[cause_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="1" />Cause A</label>
   </span>
   <span class="checkbox">
     <label for="organisation_cause_ids_2" name="organisation[cause_ids]">
     <input class="check_boxes optional" id="organisation_cause_ids_2" name="organisation[cause_ids][]" type="checkbox" value="2" />Hunger</label>
   </span>
  ...
```

Edit: The problem was due to the lazy loading of the 'Causes' I created with the factories. They weren't being created so the page had no checkboxes.

Answer (score 1):

Try with this

```
find_by_id('organisation_cause_ids_1').find("checkbox[value='1']").select_option
```

or maybe with this

```
find(:css, ".check_boxes[value='1']").set(true)
```

Comment: Thanks, but the same error on both of those :( Capybara::ElementNotFound:
       Unable to find css ".check_boxes[value='1']"

Comment: hmm i tried with this second solution and for me worked. I have capybara 2.1.0 and rspec-rails 2.14

Comment: Thanks Panczo. I finally worked out that it was a problem in my factory/lazy loading of the causes when running the tests. So there were no checkboxes displayed when running the test. I should have dumped the page during the test to check that earlier.